# change value from last column last row in R dataframe using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to change the last column last value from R dataframe.

I know I can use base R this way:

```
df[nrow(), ncol()] <- "my value"
```

But I would like to use tidy approach

What i tried so far:

```
# the last row and column to mutate by name

df %>% slice(1) %>% mutate(my_last_column="my value")
```

But I really would like to do it without knowing the column name.

Comment: Please see my edited answer and let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few options using `dplyr` and example `mtcars` data.frame:

To get the last *row*, try:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  filter(row_number() == n())
```

or

```
mtcars %>%
  slice_tail(n = 1)
```

To get the last *column*, try:

```
mtcars %>%
  select_at(ncol(.))
```

or

```
mtcars %>%
  select(tail(names(.), 1))
```

If you want to `mutate` the last row and last column, you could try this.

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate_at(ncol(.), funs(ifelse(row_number() == n(), -1, .)))
```

This would change the value in the last row and column to -1.